# getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java

I'm getting the following **error message**:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  LU62XnsCvr
>   (wrong name: APPC_LU62/java/LU62XnsCvr)

What I don't understand is that I have a set of class files compiled from the source 
in a class directory structure that mimics the package statement

**e.g.**

> C:>set CLASSPATH=C:\APPC_LU62\java
>
> C:>java LU62XnsCvr Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LU62XnsCvr (wrong name:
>   APPC_LU62/java/LU62XnsCvr)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:265)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:506)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:77)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:905)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:427)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:311)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:609)
>
> C:>
>
> C:>cd APPC_LU62\java
>
> C:\APPC_LU62\java>dir /p  Volume in drive C has no label.  Volume
>   Serial Number is B62B-74FF
>
> Directory of C:\APPC_LU62\java
>
> 05/04/2011  05:34 AM              . 05/04/2011  05:34 AM    
>   .. 05/03/2011  06:53 PM             1,492
>   LU62XnsCvr$cntrl_status.class 05/03/2011  06:53 PM             1,253
>   LU62XnsCvr$recv_status.class 05/03/2011  06:53 PM             1,689
>   LU62XnsCvr$system_code.class 05/03/2011  06:53 PM            15,230
>   LU62XnsCvr.class
>                  4 File(s)         19,664 bytes
>                  2 Dir(s)  676,075,888,640 bytes free

In the beginning of the source code I have ...

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------- 
// * LU6.2 Transceiver 
 *---------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
package APPC_LU62.java ; 

import java.nio.* ; 

import java.nio.channels.* ; 

import COM.ibm.eNetwork.cpic.* ; 

import java.io.* ; 

// bring in date-time functionality 
import java.util.Date ; 
import java.text.DateFormat ; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat ; 

public class LU62XnsCvr extends Object
```

There's no apparent mis-spelling that I can see.

The code compiles cleanly ...

Any ideas, suggestions, and comments are appreciated.

Thanks

Best regards

Guy Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `java APPC_LU62.java.LU62XnsCvr`

Comment: Hi Kal thanks for the suggestion... However I am curious as to why

Comment: because you've packaged it, and thus need to call it explicitly by its package name.